# How to disable PHP cutting off parts of long arguments in exception stack trace?

Tags: php, exception

Sometimes things like this happen:

```
#0 /some/path(1): Class_Name->exception_trigger()
#1 /some/other/path(5):  get_to('/some/long/path/tha...')
```

How do I get to see the full arguments for everything?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll have to replace the uncaught exception handler. Example:

```
function exception_handler($exception) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($exception->getTrace() as $frame) {
        echo sprintf("#%d %s(%d): %s(%s)\n",
            $i++, $frame["file"], $frame["line"],
            $frame["function"],
            implode(", ", array_map(
                function ($e) { return var_export($e, true); }, $frame["args"])));
    }
}

set_exception_handler('exception_handler');
```

Now you'll get something like:

```
#0 /home/glopes/a.php(21): a('loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong argument')
#1 /home/glopes/a.php(24): b()
```

Comment: Keep in mind that $frame['file'] is not always defined so you'll need to check it first. PHP's stack dumper returns '[internal function]' in that case. Also, you may want to see if $frame['class'] is defined and dump that too in case function is a member function.

Comment: In PHP7 i've get `Uncaught ErrorException: set_exception_handler() expects the argument (exception_handler) to be a valid callback`

Comment: This is interesting, however if I caught an exception in PHP 7 and call exception_handler($exception) (not through `set_exception_handler`), I get an error `"var_export does not handle circular references"`. Is there a way to call this function arbitrarily?

Comment: I get `var_export does not handle circular references` even if I call set_exception_handler('exception_handler');

Answer (score 5):

If you're using [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/index.php) you can [specify the length and number of variables](http://xdebug.org/docs/display) it spits out.

Comment: Good idea, but it's not for production where we usually have that disabled.

Answer (score 1):

open **php.ini** add to the bottom new line:

```
zend.exception_string_param_max_len = 64 (default = 15)
```

Reload php-fpm.
Be happy!