# PHP cuts off parts of long arguments in exception stack traces. How to tell it not to?

Tags: php, error-handling

Below is an example of the error message from PHP 7 runtime:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class
>   'Predis\Connection\ConnectionException' not found in predis.php:4168
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 /var/www/api/libraries/predis/predis.php(4455):
>   Predis\Connection\AbstractConnection->onConnectionError('Error while
>   rea...')

Note ellipsis in the first stack trace line line marked #0:

> ('Error while rea...')

That's where the most important information would have been, had it not been cut off. Other error messages have the same problem, often cutting off very valuable parts of the message.

Is there a setting that we can use to print more information in stack traces? The exact version of PHP we're using is 7.1.1.

**Update** The exact issue we're having is described in [How to disable PHP cutting off parts of long arguments in exception stack trace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481419/how-to-disable-php-cutting-off-parts-of-long-arguments-in-exception-stack-trace). This question can be closed a dupe. The idea is to catch the exception, call Exception::getTrace() and construct the error message manually. The exception can be caught in the global hander, or in each try/catch block. The default implementation of Exception::getTraceAsString truncates long function arguments.

Comment: I'm quite baffled. Was this the same behaviour before a possible upgrade in the same version? Here's something that could be related http://stackoverflow.com/q/3481419/1415724

Comment: ^ can you respond to my above comment? There may be relevance.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think it's a red herring. As I noted in my answer, this is catching an error being thrown by a error-catcher (`onConnectionError`). Either way, I think he needs to catch a `Throwable` and we might see what the real issue is. The output above looks a lot like [getTraceAsString](http://php.net/manual/en/throwable.gettraceasstring.php)

Comment: @Machavity Guess I should have put in an answer. Maybe then they'd *maybe, just maybe* respond.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, thank you for the link. That's the exact problem we're having, and I think their solution should for for us. My example in the question may not best as it brought some unnecessary context. The version is not important, as the same behavior happens in 5.6 and possibly others.

Comment: @Alex You're welcome. I noticed your voting to close as a duplicate, so I closed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the calls that might fail in a `try { ... } catch (Exception $e) { ... }` block, you can display as much of the exception error messages as you wish.

You will also be able to control what you code does with the error, or helping to better avoid the issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The error output generated for exception messages is handled by the installed debugger. The default that comes with PHP isn't that informative and you can not customize that output.

You can attach your own error handler and print your own stack traces, or you can change the debugger installed in PHP.

If you install xDebug or Zend debugger you get more information in the stack trace.

https://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use getTraceAsString();

```
<?php
   function test() {
     throw new Exception;
   }

  try {
       test();
  } catch(Exception $e) {
       echo $e->getTraceAsString();
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Tried getTraceAsString() — it does truncate the function arguments. The solution seems to to use getTrace() and build the error message manually. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481419/how-to-disable-php-cutting-off-parts-of-long-arguments-in-exception-stack-trace.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to realize you have multiple layers here. This is the actual error

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Predis\Connection\ConnectionException' not found in predis.php:4168

Note that it's uncaught `Error`. Your code likely doesn't support the PHP 7.0+ method of catching errors. As such, PHP errors out. As to why you're getting the truncation

> #0 /var/www/api/libraries/predis/predis.php(4455): Predis\Connection\AbstractConnection->onConnectionError('Error while rea...')

There's two problems here

1. `Error while rea...` is the truncated *argument*
2. `Predis\Connection\AbstractConnection->onConnectionError` This looks like an error catching mechanism. I suspect this isn't your root problem, it's just the symptom

So, can we get around this? Yes!

Whatever you're doing needs to be wrapped in a [`Throwable` block](http://php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php). `Throwable` will catch anything that can be thrown, including your `Error`

```
try { 
    \Your\Code\Here('Hi mom!');
} catch(\Throwable $err) {
    echo $err->getMessage();
}
```